# Hiding some parts of image layer with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, layers, masking

## **My Problem**

I'm currently displaying a layer image above a *Google Maps* base layer. I would like, when the user check/uncheck some checkboxes, that **some parts** of this image layer *disappear*, and the **base layer** *appears instead* these parts.
**But I want the other parts still visible with the same opacity.**

---

## **Explanations**

The image parts to hide are **polygons**. *Those polygons are already generated as layers* and are above my image layer. I could put a black background color to hide the wanted image parts, but it wouldn't display the base layer instead...
I'm stuck.

---

## **Solutions I thought about**

I would like you to say me if that's possible and, if you can, how to do it.

*I'm not asking for some code, I can do it myself, I'm just kind of a newbie at OpenLayers and I'd like someone to help me to understand how it works. Plus, I have to add functionalities to an already written code so it's not very easy.*

Here are data I have, I removed the ones which are not useful (this is only an example, empty data are usually filled with correct values).

The images :

```
images[id] = {
    name: "Image",
    image_date: '2012/08/25',
    image_path : 'static/path/to/image',
    width : '250',
    height : '250',
    georef_north : '',
    georef_south : '',
    georef_east : '',
    georef_west : ''
};
```

And the polygons :

```
polygons[id] = {
    name:'',
    longitude:'',
    latitude:''
};
```

I'm getting them like that via WFS protocol like this :

```
layers['blockLayer'][i] = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Block", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
        filter: VMMS.GIS.GetBlockFilter(i),
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            url:  "../vine/jsGeoserver",
            version: "1.1.0",
            featureType: "block",
            featureNS : urlGeoserver + dataStore ,
            featurePrefix : dataStore ,
            srsName: "EPSG:900913",
            //srsName: "EPSG:4326",
            geometryName: "block_geom",
            schema : urlGeoserver +"wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&typename=" + dataStore +":block"

        }),
        projection : proj_spherMerc,
        //projection : proj_WGS84,
        styleMap : StyleBlockWithOpacity
    });
```

### First Solution

> Why wouldn't we put the image layer in each polygon layer, and display only the layers we want to display ?

Would that work?

I'm not actually sure about that and I don't want to get into it if it's not realizable. Because I don't know if I can display an image IN a layer and not entire, and it has to be well placed in the map and in the layer... Though it seems to me it's doable.

### Second Solution

> Why wouldn't we display the base layer again above the image to hide some parts?

> The image would still be here, but as the base layer would be on top
> of it, we wouldn't see it.

This solution seems to me even less doable, or, at least, **very** heavy.

An example image, it's what I'm currently displaying : There's the google maps base layer, then the image blue and green, and all forms are polygons layers above the image.
[Screenshot](http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/6910/screenshotfrom201208211.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to host your image polygons as WMS using Geoserver, ArcGIS Server or something similar. Each image polygon representing a different feature.

Then use [OpenLayers.Layer.WMS](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/WMS-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.WMS) to add it as a layer in OpenLayers.

Then as the user clicks to hide them you provide the WMS layer with a [filter](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/filter.html) which would only show the features/images you want by ID or some other property. like:

[GeoServer Docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html)

```
http://<hostname>/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&....&cql_filter=IN ('id_1','id_2','id_3')
```

Here are some different ways you could modify the WMS filters:

- [Non_CQL](https://gist.github.com/1307324)
- [CQL](http://www.azavea.com/blogs/labs/2011/06/using-the-cql_filter-parameter-with-openlayers-wms-layers/)